# Spring JPA transaction across methos

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, transactional

I have a spring repository with 2 methods, these 2 methods can be called separately as well as together also.
I can make separate method invokation transactional using @Transactional annotation but how to make transaction across methods. Aim is to rollback method1 also when method2 update fails.

Comment: please check it https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: Instead of describing the problem, add the code with which you require help. Also show the three cases where the methods are called separately and as part of the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define propagation of the `@Transactional`.

Mark all the methods with

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

REQUIRED means it opens a new transaction if there is no opened one from invoking method. If there is a transaction opened higher it is just used.

If you need a separate transaction use `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`

Read more [here](https://simone-folino.blogspot.com.by/2012/06/spring-required-vs-requiresnew.html)

Comment: I am using springBoot and extending JpaRepository interface,  there is no code only interface method annotated with Transactional annotation, how to make 2 methods annotated with Transactional annotation to be in same transaction.